# Making "slide from bottom" button (similar to snackbar) (Android)

Tags: android, button, snackbar

there's something I want to do but don't know how... that would be a button that slides from the bottom of the screen to a certain position, triggered by something. Very similar to how snackbar show, with the difference that it stays in place instead of disappearing and has the property of being "clickable". This would NOT be a panel draggable from the bottom, but a panel that slides automatically triggered by something.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look at the translate animation examples. It is used for moving some view from some point to another point at the specified duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a fairly straightforward animation along the `y` axis, with a start value that matches the height of the screen (such that it renders just off screen), to whatever the final value is. Below code is from memory, but it should work.

To grab the screen height:

```
int getScreenHeight() {

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    return displaymetrics.heightPixels;

}
```

And to animate a view (in this case, to 80% of the total screen height):

```
void animateOnScreen(View view) {

    final int screenHeight = getScreenHeight();
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "y", screenHeight, (screenHeight * 0.8F));
    animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.start();

}
```

Comment: Oh by the way... I have a listview in the layout where the view is sliding on, do you know how I can create extra space so the sliding panel pushes the listview and therefore not hide the last item/items in the list?

Comment: @LuchitoMarcano You're welcome! As for your second issue, I'd imagine the answers lies in using `CoordinatorLayout` - if wrapping your layout `xml` file in this type of layout doesn't automatically shuffle views around in response to an animation, the [Snackbar source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.java) may giv eyou some further ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Sliding a View down by a distance:

```
view.animate().translationY(distance);
```

You can later slide the View back to its original position like this:

```
view.animate().translationY(0);
```