# Animate visibility of a view from gone to visible with animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, visibility

I have a view that is `invisible` by default(Just for the first time).

Now I need to switch the visibility to `VISIBLE` with this `animation`:

```
if (myView.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
    myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    myView.animate().translationY(0);
 }
```

(Like the SnackBar default animation)

But this isn't working. It will turn visible with default animation

Is there any simple way that I could achieve this?

**Note**

I'm animating my view to dismiss, like this:

```
myView.animate().translationY(myView.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can do this using `XML` animation.

Create a `slide-up` animation `XML` using `set` and `alpha` and put this `XML` into your resource `anim` folder.

**slide_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

**USE:**

Use `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation()` to load animation from `XML` and set and start animation using `.startAnimation()` method.

**Here is an example:**

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

// slide-up animation
Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_up);

if (imageView.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageView.startAnimation(slideUp);
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: I have updated my answer. Its now showing slide up animation as like snackbar

Comment: thanks for the reply, your solution is working too, and I'm gonna accept it because it looks cleaner to me.

Comment: Glad to know that. If my answer seems useful, please give an upvote. Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for the solution, I wanted to do the exact thing when I am trying to make the view GONE, but it doesn't work, and invisible the view at once, is there something I should do differently in this position?

Comment: hey @ArashAfsharpour same problem here, did you find any solution?

Comment: @VivekThummar did the fix in other ways, without visible and gone, I used this:
yourSecondView.animate().translationX(context.toPx(-280));
yourFirstView.animate().translationY(context.toPx(-98));

Answer (score 18):

**Add animations using ConstraintLayout**

Just add below code **above the views** whose visibility is updated:

```
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout)
```

> Note:
>
> - ConstraintLayout will only perform animation on its direct children since it only knows when you change layout parameters and constraints on the children that it handles.
> - ConstraintLayout only animates layout related changes.

For more see this post https://robinhood.engineering/beautiful-animations-using-android-constraintlayout-eee5b72ecae3

Comment: This option is interesting, it even updates recycleView faster, even though i have implemented it on another layout.

Answer (score 13):

This is the best way to **animate** views **visibility** :

```
private void viewGoneAnimator(final View view) {

    view.animate()
            .alpha(0f)
            .setDuration(500)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

}

private void viewVisibleAnimator(final View view) {

    view.animate()
            .alpha(1f)
            .setDuration(500)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

}
```

And then call this method wherever you wanted to make a view **visible** or **gone** and give the intended view to methods as the parameter.

Comment: Hey, in case of making it visible, it doesn't animate :( I have used the same methods mentioned above.

Comment: The fix for this is to use the `onAnimationStart()`callback for `viewVisibleAnimator`

Answer (score 8):

Just You need to add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your layout.
When I set visibility gone to `linear_container`, `linear_bottom` will animate from bottom to up and take place of "linear_container".

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

       <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       </LinearLayout>
       <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much out of all this is the best answer for me!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34598798/7556518) answer:

with this methods, I can set the `visibility` of my view to `VISIBLE` with a `slideUp` animation(Like `snackbar` animation):

```
int getScreenHeight() {
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    return displaymetrics.heightPixels;
}

public void animateOnScreen(View view) {
    final int screenHeight = getScreenHeight();
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "y", screenHeight, (screenHeight * 0.8F));
    animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animator.start();
}
```

Then I can use it like this:

```
if (myView.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
    myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    animateOnScreen(myView);
}
```